# (Measure Theory) how to proof closed subset in regularity of Lebesgue measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

a saw some proofs of Lebesgue regularity and open set G (for E $\in \mathcal{L}$) such that $\lambda(G\setminus E) < \varepsilon$, but how to proof this one:
Namely suppose $E \in \mathcal{L}$ is such that for $\varepsilon > 0 $ there exist a closed set $F \subset E$ such that $\lambda(E\setminus F) < \varepsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

$E \in \mathcal{L} \implies  E^c \in \mathcal{L}$

Now, given any $\epsilon >0$ , $\exists G $ open set such that $E^c \subset G$ and
$\lambda(G\setminus E^c) <\epsilon$

As, $E^c\subset G \implies G^c\subset E$

Then, $G^c =F$ is a closed set and

$\lambda(G\setminus E^c) =\lambda(E\setminus F) <\epsilon$